# Adding a page in MS Word document using VBA adds extra pages

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have MS word file with macro having table in the first page.
(Table is created using labels).

But When cells in table is not sufficient I want to add another page, with the similar table in it.

So I am trying to code as below

> ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Range.Copy
>
> ActiveDocument.Sections.Add.Range.Paste

But this code some time changes the format of first page.
And also create third blank page with second page having content of first.

Can any body let me know how to add only a page having same content of first page,
without changes in first page.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table will flow into the next page automatically, and you can specify repeating heading rows as well.

But assuming you need a new table...

Your original question needs some clarifications (see some points below), but see if the following code spoils your formatting:

```
Sub copytable1()
Dim rtarget As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
  rtarget.InsertBreak Type:=Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak
  Set rtarget = .Range(.Content.End - 1, .Content.End - 1)
  rtarget.FormattedText = .Tables(1).Range.FormattedText
  Set rtarget = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

It assumes that

- the table you want to copy is the first table in the document
- you just want to insert a new page at the end of the document and insert a copy of the table after that. If your document can already be multi-page, you would need significantly different code.

When creating editable Word documents, as a "good practice," you would use a paragraph style with the "Page Break Before" property set to achieve the break, rather than a hard page break as I have done.

Alternatively,

```
Sub copytable3()
Dim rtarget As Word.Range
With ActiveDocument
  Set rtarget = .Range
  rtarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rtarget.InsertParagraphAfter
  Set rtarget = .Range
  rtarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rtarget.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = True
  Set rtarget = .Range
  rtarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rtarget.InsertParagraphAfter
  Set rtarget = .Range
  rtarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rtarget.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = False
  Set rtarget = .Range
  rtarget.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  rtarget.Select
  rtarget.FormattedText = .Tables(1).Range.FormattedText
  Set rtarget = Nothing
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello bibadia,

Thanks for your reply,

Your assumptions are exactly matching my requirements.

But when I run your code I am getting run time error '4198' on below line....  
rtarget.InsertBreak Type:=Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak

I think it can not create range object in previous line.

I am using Excel 2013.

Please let me know if you know more about this.

Thanks

Comment: If you are running VBA from Excel, using "ActiveDocument" isn't going to work unless you (at least) qualify it with the name of the Word object you have got, e.g. when you CreateObject or GetObject. If you're already doing that, then I suggest you edit your original post to show us the code you are currently working with.

Comment: Hello Sir,Sorry for giving wrong information I am using Office 2013. I am running macro from word it self, Not from excel... Thanks

Comment: I've edited my post with an alternative. But does your document have anything unusual (image, content control, proptected field, etc.) at its end?

Comment: Hello Sir, Thanks for reply. I tried your second code but it giving error at the same line. From another source I found the code which is using "rtarget.InsertBreak wdSectionBreakNextPage". this is working. is it ok to use ?

Comment: It would be better to use a page break. Does "target.insertbreak wdpagebreak" (without the quotes) work?

Comment: I've posted another alternative that avoids hard page breaks and removes some of the things that seem to be causing problems for you. I am sure you could use a much shorter piece of VBA, but I have to say that in other cases I generally end up using a sequence of Set rtarget, followed by rtarget.Collapse, followed by inserting the thing you want, because it seems to be more reliable as a general approach.